# Is it me or is the tx_in table completely unnecessary in dbSync?

Tags: cardano-db-sync

If I've understood the dbsync schema properly then the `tx_in` table is completely unnecessary. The two fields (`tx_in_id` & `redeemer_id`) should just be brought into the `tx_out` table and left null when a UTXO has not yet been consumed. This would be far more intuitive, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

db-sync is insert only. You need to be able to see what the state was at any particular point in time. If it modified rows that wouldn't allow you to do so.

Comment: Got it. But for my purposes (analysis) lt seems like can merge the tables without messing up the data. Cool.